# How to add Richtextbox(multiline textbox) control in pagelayout?

Tags: page-layout, rich-text

I have a pagelayout, in which I want to add richtextbox(multiline type textbox of sharepoint).

how can I add this type of control?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the InputFormTextBox :

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox runat="server" ID="idRichTxtBox" Rows="10" RichText="true" TextMode="MultiLine" RichTextMode="FullHtml" AllowHyperlink="true" ></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>
```